# Reputation update delay

Tags: support, reputation

I answered a question and forgot some detail. Then I received two downvotes.

Then, I removed my answer, but SO didn't update my reputation, considering -4 for that question:

[image: Reputation]

Is there a delay on updating or are downvotes considered even removing the answer?

**UPDATE**

Observing the image, they are considering 2 events (aggregated in the header), but showing me 3 events in the details.

Comment: Yes, there is a delay.  It should take a few minutes at the most.

Comment: You should not get in the habbit of deleting old posts. You should not be posting them in the first place.

That said I generally delete posts where there is some jerk posting negative or rude comments deliberately. I come here to learn not to get criticism. Joke: I have a SO at home for that.

Comment: @JPK You are supposed to learn from criticism... the internet may not be for you. And if someone posts genuinely rude comments, you can flag them as rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @[Anonymous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3150271/anonymous) just said: The site has a short delay because everything on the server side is cached meaning that you will have to wait a few minutes for changes to take place.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. It was 42 min ago. I will give you all a feedback when SO update my reputation.

Comment: @Nizam your rep, as shown on meta, is cached more heavily so it could take an hour to update.  But your rep when viewed from the main site should update in a few minutes.

Comment: It is not updated in the main site yet (50 min right now). But as I observed in my update of the question, it is clearly that the points of remotion is not being considered (to count events and to sum the points).

Comment: @Nizam looks like you did some concurrent editing about the same time (+6 rep from suggested edits about an hour ago).  Are you sure your rep update wasn't mixed in there?  If you want to see what your official reputation is, go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation.  It is a text reprentation of your rep as it is calculated.  The very last entry will have your current rep.  This is not cached.  If it matches what you have now, then you lost track of your rep and what you are seeing is correct.  If it doesn't match, then just wait.  It will eventually update.

Answer (score 3):

Just for records, as well observed by @psubsee2003, I lost track of my reputation because SO showed me the same event twice.

[image: Reputation]

The above image shows the 5th event +4 for:

> - 05 changes to 5 when i try to .nthl() using jqyery

And bellow SO aggregates this post, including +4 because the remotion of the post, but not considering it to total reputation.

The same occurred with accepted editions I've made - I lost the points because the OP removed the question after my edition being accepted and the answer edited by me was removed:

> - mod_auth_token on a directory listing
> - SQL query: convert

The most important observation is there is a place to look the official reputation without delay or cache - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)